# How to properly redirecting AJAX call, when there are multiple AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

My scenario simplyfied:

1. Start the first AJAX request (A)
2. Start the second AJAX request (B)
3. (A) has an error, and a redirected*1 is maded.
4. (B) then finish, and it leads to a crash for the user. (User wasn't redirected afterall)

*1:

```
public class ShieldWebUserCmpBu : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Some error orcurred/unauthorised check here.. (same scenario)

        // Redirect
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { 
                                { "controller", "Unauthorised" }, { "action", "Index" } });
    }
}
```

I understand you can't cancel a AJAX request and I might have had my self convinced a redirect would "cancel" the other request(s).

So correct me if im on the wrong track, but should the solution then be to add some kind of valid/redirect check everywhere I handle my AJAX request, asking if the site was redirecting since it was started, so I could discard the result manually?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page - an ajax call will never redirect.

Comment: Ahh the problem was set `filterContext.Result` with a view, and the return type was JsonResult. And it would break trying to parse the view(html page) into Json.